# How can I create an xml schema that will take the data from an xml file and transpose the rows into columns?

Tags: xml, excel

I have an XML file that is pulled from a database and, using Excel, is creating multiple rows to display different numbers for an individual person and I want those rows to be transposed to multiple columns. So when someone looks at that person they only have to scroll to the right to see the numbers.

Currently each row is organized by 1-27 in a column to the left of the numbers and I was hoping to make these the headers in the columns with the corresponding numbers underneath.

Here is an example of the XML file that the database is outputting.

```
<B15C>
    <PP nbr="1">
        <AMT>55555</AMT>
        </PP>
        <PP nbr="2">
            <AMT>4561</AMT>
        </PP>
        <PP nbr="3">
            <AMT>5646354</AMT>
        </PP>
        <PP nbr="4">
            <AMT>321546</AMT>
        </PP>
        <PP nbr="5">
            <AMT>221321</AMT>
        </PP>
        <PP nbr="27">
            <AMT>3110.41</AMT>
        </PP>
</B15c>
```

Here is an example of the part of the schema that outputs this data

```
<xs:element name="B15C">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="PP">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="AMT" type="xs:decimal" />
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute name="nbr" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I am new to XML so I am not even sure if this can be done. If it can't are there any alternatives apart from using VBA or manually altering the XML file?

I have pictures but the site won't allow me to post them since I am a new user, sorry!

Thanks for the help

Comment: Whether you have a schema to describe the xml for the transformed file, is up to you. But if you want to transform XML documents, and you don't want to "hard code" it. The thing you are looking for is XSLT, mind you it's a pretty steep learning curve....

Answer (score 0):

A schema describes an XML file and validates that it conforms to the description. It won't ever change the file (except in trivial ways for example by adding default values).

You are wanting to transform one XML file into another. The tool for that is XSLT.

You've described your XML in terms of columns and rows, but when I look at it all I see are elements. to help you transform this to a different XML file, we'll need to know what you want that XML file to look like - in terms of XML, not in terms of "rows and columns", which are concepts external to the XML.

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of the XSLT file that was needed to transform the XML file. I will look into it right away.